# Unit testing http handlers in golang mocking dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection

At the moment I try to establish best practices for unit testing go handlers.
I need to mock dependencies, but therefore I have to be able to access / mock these dependencies.

There I some solutions I do not want to consider like for example global variables / application state. Or having all handlers as functions of a struct holding the dependencies member variables.

I was kind of satisfied with a solution where I injected the needed dependencies of a handler in the following way:

```golang
func helloHandler(db *DbService) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *httpRequest) {
    // handler code goes here
  }
}
```

Then I am able to provide this handler for routing:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHander(myDbService))
```

I can also test it easily:

```golang
helloHandler(myDbService)(req, respRecorder)
```

But when I use for example gorilla mux (what I haven't considered from the beginning) I get another problem.

Gorilla/mux adds extra semantics like filtering by Method (GET / POST), providing path parameters etc.

So I should need to test the resulting gorilla router.
But then I am again not able to inject my mock dependencies anymore.

When I get the router back everything (dependencies) is already set up.

But I also don't want to rebuild my Router in my tests because of DRY!

So for now I don't really have a good solution for the problem of conveniently setting up my routes but also being able to mock the dependencies.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I personally changed my Router function into a method with a Receiver, so I can create Mock receivers:

#### Production code:

```
func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    version.AddRouter(router, contextRoot)
    someStruct := SomeStruct{SomeDependency{}}
    router.HandleFunc(contextRoot, someStruct.HandleRequests).
           Methods(http.MethodGet)
}

func (s SomeStruct) HandleRequests(writer http.ResponseWriter, reader *http.Request) {
    ...
}

func (s SomeDependency) SomeFunctionCalledFromHandler(...) SomeReturnStruct {
    ...
    return SomeReturnStruct{}
}
```

#### Unit test:

```
type mockWriter struct {}
type someMockDependency struct {}
func Test_HandleRequest1(t *testing.T) {

    someStructMockDeps := SomeStruct{someMockDependency{}}
    someStructMockDeps.HandleRequests(mockWriter{}, &http.Request{URL: &url.URL{RawQuery:"http://dummy-query.com"}});

    assert.Equal(...)
}
func (someMockDependency) SomeFunctionCalledFromHandler(...) SomeReturnStruct {
    ...
    return SomeReturnStruct{}
}
```

#### Integration test:

```
func TestHandlerFuncIntg(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        println("skipping")
        t.Skip()
     }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/hello?param=value", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    someStructMockDeps := SomeStruct{someMockDependency{}}
    handler :=   http.HandlerFunc(someStructMockDeps.HandleRequests)

    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rr.Code)
    assert.Equal(t, "This is my result", rr.Body.String())
}

func (someMockDependency) SomeFunctionCalledFromHandler(...) SomeReturnStruct {
    ...
    return SomeReturnStruct{}
}
```

`SomeStruct` declares the dependencies (as Dependency Injection) so they can be overridden for tests.